# How to publish a pip package: Cannot import although listed under conda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, publishing

I have created a pip package named [ezimage](https://pypi.org/project/ezimage/) and published it to PyPi by following [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/executable-package-pip-install), step by step. However, when I install it in a conda environment using `pip install ezimage`, I cannot import the package, getting the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ezimage'` error message despite the package being listed when running `conda list`. I have successfully installed other pip packages in conda. I appreciate any help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `setup.py` has code [`packages=setuptools.find_packages()`](https://github.com/Miladiouss/ezImage/blob/1306a9ba2daa27ed34ba1f78f9afe8cd9cd2e27f/setup.py#L14) but your [code](https://github.com/Miladiouss/ezImage/tree/1306a9ba2daa27ed34ba1f78f9afe8cd9cd2e27f) doesn't have any [packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages), it only has a module `ezImage.py`. Replace the line with:

```
py_modules=['ezImage'],
```

See [`distutils`' docs](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-individual-modules).